# Body Background based on hour of the day JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var dt = new Date();
   var currentHour = dt.getHours();
   $('body').css('background', '#FFF url(https://crystalforums.cf/bk/bk_'+currentHour+'.png) no-repeat center center fixed');
   $('body').css('background-size', 'cover');
});
</script>
```

Hey! I had this script working on a my forum and i tried working it on a my website index, but it seems to not work. They both use the `body` thingy (I forgot the actual term, it's Saturday and i got a ton of work) so they should effect the body element right? What am i doing wrong, the script suppose to set the background image of the website to a new image based on every hour. Help???

I don't want it to auto update, they cxan refresh. I want so there is one background for every hour.

Comment: `.ready()` handler is run only once

Comment: Is body the visble background element? Meaning is there maybe some other element that covers the entire page that you should be changing instead?

Comment: No, there is no background on the website theme atm. @PatrickEvans

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550206/javascript-run-a-function-every-quarter-hour-at-00-15-30-45

Comment: [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxoqLmfc/) to see what I meant by another element blocking `<body>`. You cannot see the green background `<body>` is set to because it is blocked by the `<div>` that has a white background. So no matter what you change `body` to it wont matter as it is blocked. The other possible reason is that you didn't include the jQuery library into your page. Make sure neither of those are your problem, and possibly provide an example page demonstrating the problem

Comment: view-source: crystalforums.cf/getbot

Comment: That url goes to a 404, but if i just go to crystalforums.cf, i find a page that does not include the jQuery library. When debugging make sure to look at the Dev Tools console (usually F12 on browsers like Chrome, IE)

Comment: view-source: crystalforums.cf/gembot is the correct url

Comment: lill go add the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` with duration set to 5 minutes `60000 * 5` or briefer duration between function calls

```
$().ready(function() {
  var interval, curr;

  function handleBackground() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var currentHour = dt.getHours();
    if (!curr || currentHour !== curr) {
      curr = currentHour;
      $('body').css('background', 'url(https://crystalforums.cf/bk/bk_' 
                   + currentHour 
                   + '.png) no-repeat center center fixed');
    }
  }
  // call `handleBackground` to set initial `background` at `body`
  handleBackground();
  interval = setInterval(handleBackground, 60000 * 5);
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/5YTPgPgaKbXfYIT0MG3x?p=preview

Comment: _"still nothing."_ What do you mean by "still nothing"? Note, requirement could probably also be achieved using `css` animation

Comment: _"Background is still white, it's not showing."_ An image, image.prntscr.com/image/39d7970dc97742aabc93f247194252c9.png , is displayed at link, here. Note, links to images usually do not help resolve issue.

Comment: @AntonioVallez The error was here. Did not initially call function which was passed to `setInterval`. See updated post

Comment: I don't think OP is wanting an executing function every hour, I think they just want a background based on the hour. Based on their last sentence in the question and their comment on another answer _"but i don't really want it to auto-update. They can refresh if they like"_

Comment: @PatrickEvans _"I think they just want a background based on the hour."_  Not certain what you mean? The function passed to `setInterval` should be called every five minutes. As mentioned at earlier comment, requirement could probably be achieved using `css`

Comment: Meaning forget setTimeout/Interval all together they don't want the background changing while the user is on the page, just different on page load. @AntonioVallez, you should edit your question to make that clear as the only part of your question that makes that apparent is the last sentence, your question title is making everyone think you want an interval function

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks. Was in the middle of defining 23 keyframes for `css` animation. _"just different on page load."_ Note, Question still does not describe requirement as new image only at page load? _"I want so there is one background for every hour."_ How is this portion of Question supposed to be fulfilled within an interval which checks how much time has elapsed since background was previously set?

Answer (score 2):

First...I don't recommend use javascript for this....Your approach needs an user for an hour into your website and in the same page...If you still think in change that you will need use `setTimeout` function...

My recommendation is using a server side technology for this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JQuery, I always use Java Script :P, 
If you want to change background after 5 Minutes you can do this by javascript

```
<script>
index = 0;
function changeBackground(){
var backColor = ["image.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg"];
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+backColor[index]+")";
index++;
if(index > (backColor.length)  - 1){
index = 0;
}
}
//1000 means 1 second, so for 5 min 
// 6,000 X 5 = 30,000
setInterval(changeBackground, 30000);
</script>
```

Just try this code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the setInterval() function like this:

```
function someFunction() {
    alert("It's been one hour");
}
setInterval(someFunction, 3600000);
```

Where the 3600000 is a hour in milliseconds.